# Multiple keys in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I was wondering how I could input a string and get more than one key from a dictionary? For example, this is my code and I want to print something like "Welcome to the underworld" and have it be encoded with the letters in my dictionary.

```
def main():
    print("*********************************************************************************************")
    print("What exactly is your use for this? Whatever, Enter a message because your hiding something...")
    print("*********************************************************************************************")

    userInput = input("Enter your message to encode: ")
    userInput = userInput.lower()
    # encoding dictionary
    encoding = {"a":"b","b":"c","c":"d","d":"e","e":"f","f":"g","g":"h","h":"i","i":"j","j":"k","k":"l","l":"m","m":"n",
                "n":"o","o":"p","p":"q","q":"r","r":"s","s":"t","t":"u","u":"v","v":"w","w":"x","x":"y",
                "y":"z","z":"a"," ":"-"}

    #userInput = encoding[key]

    for key in encoding:
        if (userInput == key):
            print(encoding[key])
            break

main()
```

Comment: For your encoding do something like `chr(ord("a")+1)` rather than write out the dictionary

Answer (score 1):

You should not iterate the `encoding`, it's the dictionary. Instead, you can just iterate the input string, replace each `character` with `encoding[character]`.

```
''.join([encoding[c] for c in somestring])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(''.join([encoding.get(letter, '') for letter in userInput]))
```

Basically, you want to loop through the input message (`userInput`) in order to encode the entire thing. The argument to join (`[encoding.get(letter, '') for letter in userInput]`) does just that: for every character in the input, it finds it's matching encoding.The `.get` is convenient too because in the case where the letter is not found (ie. if the user entered a digit), the character is the empty string.

`''.join(something)` takes all the elements in `something` and puts it together as a string. More generally, `'a string'.join(something)` would put `'a string'` between every element of `something`, so if `'a string'` is empty, the empty string is put in between, effectively joining everything in the list into a string.

Comment: Can you explain whats going on in that line, like i'm 5?